# Component child selector with extended template

Tags: angular, angular7, view-hierarchy

I want to create component with view hierarchy outside of Router and RouterModule

Example:

comp-parent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'comp-parent',
  template: `
        <p>parent works</p>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        `,
  styleUrls: ['./comp-parent.css']
  })
export class ComponentParent { 
    protected foo: string;
}
```

comp-children.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'comp-children',
  template: "<p>Children works</p>",
  styleUrls: ['./comp-children.css']
  })
export class ComponentChildren extends ComponentParent { }
```

component-foo-bar.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-foo-bar',
  template: "<comp-children></comp-children>",
  styleUrls: ['./component-bar.css']
  })
export class ComponentFooBar { }
```

In `ComponentBar` I would expect that `comp-children` will be `comp-parent` with `comp-children` included, but only `comp-children` template is loaded.

How to load parent template with `<router-outlet/>` resolved to `comp-children` template?

Comment: In your component-foo-bar.ts file, you used a templateUrl but gave the html directly. Is it a mistake in posting the code?

Comment: yep, typo. Fixed.

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of Router and RouterModule" and using `router-outlet`?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-foo-bar',
  template: "<comp-children>",
  styleUrls: ['./component-bar.css']
  })
export class ComponentFooBar { }
```

with

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-foo-bar',
  template: "<comp-children></comp-children>",
  styleUrls: ['./component-bar.css']
  })
export class ComponentFooBar { }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit a class, only you can use the logic of the base class but not the template of it.

Infact, you have not used the child component inside the parent component. ( I meant using child component selector in parent component template)

So they are not parent and child actually and they are just base and derived classes

Comment: It would be better if you post your entire code on stack blitz

Comment: Router and state routing works like i described, (if you define proper RoutingModule), but i want to use it outside of URL routing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make such hierarchy you don't need to use `router-outlet` nor inheritance. Just use components directly (by selectors). See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9dgdk) demo.

Comment: It's part of bigger mechanism, I can't use children in parent component like provided in your example because its not extending base template. It simply uses `children-component` inside `parent-component`.